# Google API returns No License for a paid Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-oauth

I have a few paid extensions in the Chrome Web Store, which work flawlessly through the Google API licensing system, but I can't make a new recently published extension work.

Every time I call for checking the license, the response is the same:

```
"{   
   "kind":"chromewebstore#userLicense",   
   "itemId":"extension_id",   
   "result":false,   
   "maxAgeSecs":"2"
}"
```

I do call the code from a Google account different than my developer account.

I tried both creating a new project in the Google Developers Console, as well as binding to the extension an unused OAuth 2.0 credential from an existing project.

The result is always the same.

Here's the code for checking the license that I use in all of my extensions (it's essentially unchanged and taken from [this](https://www.nuanced.it/2016/09/setting-up-chrome-extensions-with-free.html) site):

```
const licenceChecker = (function licenceCheckModule() {
    const CWS_LICENSE_API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/userlicenses/';
    let trialPeriodDays = 0;
    let verbose = false;
    let cachedResult;
    let tsCacheExpiration = 0;
    let accessToken;

    const init = function init(params) {
        if (params.trialPeriodDays) {
          trialPeriodDays = params.trialPeriodDays;
        }
        if (params.verbose) {
         verbose = true;
        }
    };

    const get = function get(cbProcessResult) {
      if (Date.now() < tsCacheExpiration) {
        if (verbose) {
          console.log('from cache', cachedResult);
        }
       cbProcessResult(cachedResult);
       return;
     }
     xhrWithAuth(
       'GET',
        CWS_LICENSE_API_URL + chrome.runtime.id, true,
        (error, status, response) => {
           const result = processResponse(error, status, response);
           cbProcessResult(result);
        }
     );
   };

  function processResponse(error, status, response) {
     if (verbose) {
        console.log(error, status, response);
     }
     const result = {};
     let data;
     if (status === 200) {
        data = JSON.parse(response);
        result.error = false;
        result.data = parseLicense(data);
        result.response = data;
        cachedResult = result;
     } else {
     result.error = true;
     result.response = response;
   }
   return result;
 }

  function parseLicense(license) {
      tsCacheExpiration = (parseInt(Date.now() / 1000, 10)
          + parseInt(license.maxAgeSecs, 10)) * 1000;
      if (!tsCacheExpiration) {
           tsCacheExpiration = 0;
      }
      if (license.result && license.accessLevel === 'FULL') {
          return 'FULL';
      } else if (license.result && license.accessLevel === 'FREE_TRIAL') {
          let daysAgoLicenseIssued = Date.now() - parseInt(license.createdTime, 10);
          daysAgoLicenseIssued = daysAgoLicenseIssued / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
          if (trialPeriodDays && daysAgoLicenseIssued <= trialPeriodDays) {
             if (verbose) {
                console.log('Free trial, still within trial period');
             }
             return 'FREE_TRIAL';
          }
          if (verbose) {
              console.log('Free trial, trial period expired.');
          }
          return 'FREE_TRIAL_EXPIRED';
      }
      if (verbose) {
         console.log('No license ever issued.');
      }
      return 'NO_LICENSE';
   }

   function xhrWithAuth(method, url, interactive, callback) {
      let retry = true;
      getToken();

      function getToken() {
         chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive }, (token) => {
             if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                 callback(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                 return;
             }
             accessToken = token;
             requestStart();
         });
       }

       function requestStart() {
           const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.open(method, url);
           xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
           xhr.onload = requestComplete;
           xhr.send();
       }

       function requestComplete() {
           if (this.status === 401 && retry) {
           retry = false;
           chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({ token: accessToken },
                                          getToken);
           } else {
               callback(null, this.status, this.response);
           }
       }
   }

   return {
     init,
     get
  };
}());

 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.cmd === 'checkLicence') {
        licenceChecker.init({
        trialPeriodDays: 1,
        verbose: false
    });
    checkLicense((isAuthorised) => {
       sendResponse(isAuthorised);
    });
  }
  return true;
});

function checkLicense(cbContinue) {
    licenceChecker.get(result => {
    chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(userInfo => {

        if (result.data === 'FULL' || result.data === 'FREE_TRIAL') {
          cbContinue({
             email: userInfo.email,
             licenced: true
          });
       } else {
          cbContinue({
             email: userInfo.email,
             licenced: false
         });
      }
   });
 });
}
```

What can be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Could it be related to [this](https://www.techradar.com/news/google-suspends-all-paid-chrome-browser-extensions)?

Comment: @Iván Nokonoko I thought about it, but since then they seem to have fixed the matter more or less. At least my other paid extensions that were suspended before, now work properly.

Comment: In order for the license response to have `"result":true` and the other license fields, the user must have had installed the extension **from Chrome Web Store**. If you install it differently, like loading it directly in chrome://extensions in developer mode, the license response will be like the one in your question.

Comment: @Iván Nokonoko You can actually use the extension in the developer mode if you add the corresponding key to the manifest, so it's not the cause of this. And even when I install the extension from the Store (I have it there published as unlisted) the error is the same.

Comment: I know you can use the extensions in developer mode adding the corresponding key to the manifest. But when you install them that way, no license is issued. The user must install the extension from Chrome Web Store. Have you published it as paid with a free trial period? In your code, the trial period seems to be 0

Comment: @Iván Nokonoko Yes well like I wrote before I also installed the extension from the store and it is still not working. The trial period is 1 day, this code is working perfectly fine with 3 other extensions of mine.